# Adding an element to the end of a List in java

Tags: java, list

I have this array that I converted into a list:

```
String[] inputArr = {"id", "+", "id", "*", "id"};
List<String> inputList = Arrays.asList(inputArr);
```

How would I go about adding a character to the end of the list since there isn't a specific add function for Lists?

Edit: Both my classes and code

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] inputArr = {"id", "+", "id", "*", "id"};
    //InQueue inQueue = new InQueue(inputArr);
    InQueue inQueue = new InQueue();

}
}

import java.util.*;

public class InQueue {
    public static String[] inputArr = {"id", "+", "id", "*", "id"};
    public static List<String> inputList = Arrays.asList(inputArr);
}
```

Comment: By using `add` method of a List

Comment: Of course the `inputList` has an `add` method. But maybe you mean something different as you talk about adding a "character" to a list of `String`s?

Comment: Because you get an immutable `List`? `List<String> inputList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(inputArr));`

Comment: @floxbr I had wanted to add "$" to the end of the list, to signal my parser to stop at the end when it sees $

Comment: @Ellio It's not an immutable list. It's normal ArrayList

Comment: Not quite: @ElliottFrisch is almost right in that the result of `Arrays.asList` in unmodifiable (not immutable, though). Therefore, you cannot actually append elements to it. You can e.g. create a new `ArrayList` from it in various ways (which you could then edit) or not even start with an array if you don't absolutely have to for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. you have an array of `String` and convert it to `List` of `String` so you cannot add a `char` to it.
2. When you do `Arrays.asList` you get `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList` (which is not a `java.util.ArrayList`). The former has not `add` function implemented, so you cannot add anything there.
3. You can construct a "normal" list (`java.util.ArrayList`) using what you currently have as a constructor parameter.

> ***N.B.*** you won't be able to add a `char` but you can add a `String`

So that the final solution would be:

```java
String[] inputArr = {"id", "+", "id", "*", "id"};
List<String> inputList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(inputArr));
inputList.add("$");
```

Probably you want to achieve something like this:

```java
import java.util.*;

class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] inputArr = {"id", "+", "id", "*", "id"};
        InQueue inQueue = new InQueue(inputArr);
        inQueue.printQueue();
    }
}

class InQueue {

    List<String> tokens;

    public InQueue(String[] input){
        tokens = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(input));
        tokens.add("$");
    }

    public void printQueue(){
        System.out.println(tokens);
    }
}
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, but it doesn't seem to be working for me. I get the error "cannot resolve symbol 'add' "

Comment: What if you just create a separate main method and copy-paste my code? This has to work. Probably you have some confusing imports..

Comment: I'm trying to use this in another class that doesn't have a main method though. I've tried creating a method add() but I can't seem to make it work

Comment: Can you show your code including class name and imports? You can leave only the method where you put that your code.

Comment: Edit to show both classes

Comment: Check my update. Probably it illustrates what you would like to have.